# Plugin or proxy that can change response content?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, proxy, plugins

On my desktop I woud like to run a proxy or a plugin that would allow one to change the responses received from the server. I would love to use Greasemonkey for this, but Greasemonkey (at least the last time I checked) can't run on requests made by the flash player.

Anyone have any ideas of something that can actually intercept the responses sent by the server and run a configurable regex or script before it gets to the Flash plugin and web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Burp Proxy should fit your needs: http://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy.html